# MSpec replacement for BDD style unit test in winrt app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, bdd, portable-class-library

Is any good tool, which could I use to BDD style unit testing, instead of MSpec, in winrt application?

As we know, MSpec is not ported to PCL [machine specification - issue 120](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/120)

Comment: Did you find anything so far?

Comment: Did you try TestStack BDDfy? http://docs.teststack.net/bddfy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions depending on what you're trying to accomplish:
If you need to test code in PCL you can create a plain old .NET (test) class and reference the PCL library.

If you're trying to test I found the [following thread](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.BDDfy/issues/154) on using BDDfy to test win81 & WP81 application using BDDfy.